# image on the button still changing i am using a condition to check whether image is already on the JButton but it is still changing

Tags: java

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
JButton temp=(JButton)e.getSource();
if(temp==Restart)
{
System.out.println("Restart button got pressed");
btn1.setIcon(null);btn2.setIcon(null);btn3.setIcon(null);btn4.setIcon(null);btn5.setIcon(null);btn6.setIcon(null);
        btn7.setIcon(null);btn8.setIcon(null);btn9.setIcon(null);
        My.flag=true;My.dr=0;
    }
    if(temp==btn1||temp==btn2||temp==btn3||temp==btn4||temp==btn5||temp==btn6||temp==btn7||temp==btn8||temp==btn9){
    if(temp.getIcon()!=img ||temp.getIcon()!=img1){
    if(My.flag==true)
    {
        temp.setIcon(img);
        My.flag=false;
        //temp.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else
    {
        temp.setIcon(img1);
        My.flag=true;
        //temp.setEnabled(false);
    }}
```

This is my action listener i am using the images on the button and i want that if a image is set on the button it should not be changed

Comment: `if button.getIcon() == null` ...?

Comment: Thank u  now it is working

Comment: @lovesoni I highly suggest you looking into `Arrays` or `Lists` would make your task much easier

Comment: For which code i should use array